# Windows Universal file picker allows videos

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I currently have a file input in my app:

`<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Select from gallery" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"/>`

This should only allow `.png` `.jpg` or `.jpeg` files to be selected but it actually allows for selection of all files when running on Windows Universal Platform. (Windows 10 Mobile).

Is there a way I can force the Windows Universal Platform to allow only selection of images? Or should I catch this after the user has selected a file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can force the Windows Universal Platform to allow only selection of images? Or should I catch this after the user has selected a file?

Instead of using FilePicker of Html, you can use [`Windows.Storage.Picers.FileOpenPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker) to accomplish that:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TestFilePicker</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <button id="btnClick">Click Me to Pick File</button>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
(function () {
"use strict"

    document.getElementById("btnClick").onclick = function (evt)
    {
        var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.thumbnail;
        openPicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
        openPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]);

        // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
        openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
            if (file) {
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            } else {
                // The picker was dismissed with no selected file
            }
        });
    }
})();
```